# Can Java Comparable<Object> fail on a max/min cross-comparison?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I've working on a depth sorting problem, here's an example case I constructed

[image]

There are two planes, one hovering above the other, and they are sectioned into rectangluar polygons. Each polygon is defined by it's 'real-world' coordinates, as well as defined with a camera and view projections to produce a perspective view, as shown. A trace-printout of an example polygon produces

```
Zn = -0.225, Zf = -0.432
v0 (13, 33, 32.7) (-0.358, -0.065, -0.295, 180.737)
v1 (29, 33, 32.7) (-0.192, -0.142, -0.225, 173.247)
v2 (29, 33,  7.2) ( 0.011,  0.023, -0.375, 190.239)
v3 (13, 33,  7.2) (-0.148,  0.087, -0.432, 197.730)
```

This sample is one belonging to the green plane `y=33`, the non-projected vertices are `v0 to v4 = (13,33,32.7),(29,33,32,7),(29, 33,7.2) and (13,33,7.2)`

The projected coordinates, using a standard camera and view model, are shown following. If `p(i)` is the projected coordinate then `-1 < p(i).x,p(i).z,p(i).z < 1`. The fourth value is the homogenous W coordinate when prepared for rendereding divided into each `p(i)(x,y,z)`, it is preserved as a reference value because it gives the distance from the 'camera' to a perpendicular plane of a given vertex.

The third column in the second series of brackets are the projected Z-values, and importantly *for this problem* The values `Zn=depth of nearest vertex`, and `Zf=depth of farthest vertex`

**The question**
This question is motivated by all of the above but is also independent of any knowledge of graphics rendering. My motivation is to depth-sort the quadrilateral polygons primarily on their *Z-values*

According to [Painter's algorithm](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/visibility/painter.htm) the first check on rendering order between two polygons is if the Z-near and Z-far are separate and should imply unambiguous spacial separation.

A simplified extract of the comparison

```java
class Extent implements Comparable<Extent> {
    double Zn;
    double Zf;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Extent ext2) {
        if (Zn < ext2.Zf) return 1;
        if (ext2.Zn < Zf) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**My Problem**
When I run the comparison against a large set of polygons, sometimes I get a 
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract` exception. While often the rendering looks good as above, sometimes it fails. But why, I haven't been able to find a fail-case, and shouldn't comparing on two max,min in this way always be transient?

Does anyone know of an example set that would fail, subjected to this comparison? And, perhaps, are you able to spot a logical error in my method? (while insight in the internals of the compare method is the primary enquiry, if you are familiar with 3d depth-sorting please feel free to comment)

Comment: @Andreas To clarify, the exception described are on calls to `Collections.sort(polygons)` where `polygons instanceof List<Extent>`. The meaning of the interface Extent is the distance of the geometries from the observer. Regarding reduction of the problem-statement, in hindsight the reduction of the problem (as the answer below) was largely the solution - advise is to your credit, had I found it. Marked as `algorithmic/graphics/3d`, the question should perhaps be named something like `why is the given sorting scheme non-transitive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm won't satisfy the [compareTo contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)), because of transitivity failure; you're not defining a *total ordering*.  Consider three `Extents`

> p1(0,3)    p2(0,1)   p3(2,3)

The implementor must ensure that `p1.compareTo(p2) == 0` implies that
`sgn(p1.compareTo(p3)) == sgn(p2.compareTo(p3))` for all other points.

`p1.compareTo(p2)` is 0.
`p1.compareTo(p3)` is 0, but `p2.compareTo(p3)` is -1.

The "best" way to sort ranges will depend on what exactly you want to do with the sorted list, but you'll most likely end up sorting on either the near, far, or center values.

Comment: I found your answer helpful and gave you a pluss in the end, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use an external `Comparator` to compare with instead of trying to implement `Comparable` which for complex objects is almost always the wrong way to do it.

`Comparable` works great for objects with a single or very few attributes that need to be the same in all cases. Like a complex object with an `ID` that is unique which is the only thing that is compared.

It does **not** work for complex cases where all the attributes are not considered in all cases. For those times you use a `Comparator` or better yet [`Ordering` from the Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained) so that you can do elegant chaining and compositions.

Also sorting on triangles makes this exercise trivial because they can never be non-planar and have one less point to compare.

Comment: previously marked (+) with a belated thanks, OpenGL preempted your lib-recommendation, holding a reminder to look out for another use!